# Erro ao mudar senha (MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD), no arquivo docker.compose.yml do MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker

Tive que recentemente mudar a senha de administrador do meu banco de dados (atualmente utilizo MySQL), mudei a senha 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' porém não refletiu mudanças em meu container.
Já tentei excluir, dar build e tentar um refresh forçado. Porém nada funcionou.

```
# arquivo docker-compose.yml
version: "2"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - default
    db:
        image: mysql:5.6
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: lista
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
        volumes:
            - ./bd:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        networks:
            - default
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - db:db
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
volumes:
    persistent:
```

Comment: Só alterar na _compose_ não vai resolver mesmo, já que estão no volume _persistent_. Acesse o container e altere a senha ou recrie o volume

Comment: Exatamente o que o @BrunoCésar falou. Fez isso?